# Using connection string login and not Application Pool Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, shared-hosting, application-pool

**The Question:**

How do I get my Web Application to use my connection string login and not the Application Pool Identity?

**The Background:**

I have started up a .net mvc project and currently use Arvixe for hosting. I made a simple page using a form to communicate with the SQL database. [Here is the site.](http://photosbyjoeforyou.com/)

Just type anything into the text boxes and hit the button. If the communication is successful, it should just return a message.

The error:

```
Cannot open database "jfphotography" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'SEAWEED\photosbyjoefor_web6'.
```

My database user is jfphoto_dbadmin. I have tried making it photosbyjoefor_web6, but with no luck. No where in my code do I use, or set anything to, photosbyjoefor_web6. I have tried using photosbyjoefor_web6 in my connection string.

My connection string is correct, and I have been chatting with support for a week now. We believe that the application is using the Application Pool identity, and, using basic services, I am not allowed/Arvixe will not make any custom Application Pool Identities (which makes sense for shared hosting). Unfortunately, I do not want to be paying 40 bucks a month for their private hosting to be able to edit the Application Pools.

My project is using a Code-First approach, data service layers, context layer, all the fun stuff. I have never encountered this type of error before, and I am unsure of how to approach it. I really do not want to re-build my project in a different manner, but if I have to so-be-it.

Connection string:

add name="PhotographyContext" connectionString="Data Source=seaweed.arvixe.com;Initial Catalog=jfphotography;Integrated Security=True;user id=jfphoto_dbadmin;password=********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: Can you add your connection string to the post? If you have integrated security / SSPI enabled and do not have a User Id / Password specified you will observe this behaviour.

Comment: Maybe post your connection string with the password obfuscated?

Comment: I guess you are using Sql Server? In that case you need to make sure that the server accepts "Sql server authentication"?

Comment: Do you have `Integrated Security=True` in the connection string?

Comment: I have added the connection string! Yeah, I had the integrated security set to true.

Comment: You need to remove "Integrated Security=True" this part from the connection string. it forces the connection to be made by windows account.

Comment: @nhrobin progress! I am getting "Invalid object name 'dbo.Client'." now! Better or worse? I have no idea. I will work with this now!

Comment: Better, the connection has been made.